# Variable not loading range value

Tags: excel, vba

This code is used to pull over data from multiple workbooks stored in a file to one single workbook using index match.

Once I've pulled over all the data into my table, I'm attempting to clean up column "N" using the "Right" function to isolate a state abbreviation from the pulled data which looks like this - "36010 - Allen, OH" (i.e. "OH").

To do this I've set `State` equal to `Range("N8").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value` where the newly pulled data lives and I want to apply the "Right" function to the data in this column to get the state abbreviation "OH".

The problem is that my variable `State` does not seem to pick up the new data pulled in by the index match - i.e. "36010 - Allen, OH". Instead it shows as `""`. Looking for any help or similar questions on how to solve this. I'm sure its something super obvious.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim PBPs As Workbook
Dim Hplan As String
Dim Folder_Path As String
Dim r As Range
Dim i As Integer
Dim State As String


 With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False 'prevent screen flickering
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual 'Preventing calculation
    .DisplayAlerts = False 'Turn OFF alerts
    .EnableEvents = False 'events all events
End With

Set wb = ThisWorkbook
Folder_Path = Range("E2").Value


    For i = 1 To Range("RunRange").Count
        
        Hplan = Range("Start").Offset(i - 1, 0)
        State = Range("N8").Offset(i - 1, 0).Value
        
        On Error GoTo 0
        Workbooks.Open Filename:=Folder_Path & "PBP_Data_Report_" & Hplan & ".xlsx"
        
        Set PBPs = ActiveWorkbook
        
        On Error Resume Next
        wb.Worksheets(1).Range("Start").Offset(i - 1, 8).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(PBPs.Worksheets(1).Range("B:B"), WorksheetFunction.Match(wb.Worksheets(1).Range("Lookup").Offset(0, 0).Value, PBPs.Worksheets(1).Range("A:A"), 0))
        wb.Worksheets(1).Range("Start").Offset(i - 1, 9).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(PBPs.Worksheets(1).Range("B:B"), WorksheetFunction.Match(wb.Worksheets(1).Range("Lookup").Offset(0, 1).Value, PBPs.Worksheets(1).Range("A:A"), 0))
        wb.Worksheets(1).Range("Start").Offset(i - 1, 10).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(PBPs.Worksheets(1).Range("B:B"), WorksheetFunction.Match(wb.Worksheets(1).Range("Lookup").Offset(0, 2).Value, PBPs.Worksheets(1).Range("A:A"), 0))
        wb.Worksheets(1).Range("Start").Offset(i - 1, 11).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(PBPs.Worksheets(1).Range("B:B"), WorksheetFunction.Match(wb.Worksheets(1).Range("Lookup").Offset(0, 3).Value, PBPs.Worksheets(1).Range("A:A"), 0))
        wb.Worksheets(1).Range("Start").Offset(i - 1, 12).Value = WorksheetFunction.Index(PBPs.Worksheets(1).Range("B:B"), WorksheetFunction.Match(wb.Worksheets(1).Range("Lookup").Offset(0, 4).Value, PBPs.Worksheets(1).Range("A:A"), 0))
        
        wb.Worksheets(1).Range("Start").Offset(i - 1, 10) = Right(State, 2)
        
        PBPs.Close
           
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: You should qualify the worksheet/workbook.

Comment: Okay I updated "wb.worksheets(1).Range("N8").offset(i-1,0).value" still getting no value for "State". Is that what you meant by qualify?

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` is not any help when trying to figure out what's going wrong in your code.  What happens if you comment that out?  Also you're setting State *before* pulling the data, so you're not going to see whatever gets queried over.  Finally, your lookup column is to the left of the return column, so you can use the shorter VLOOKUP() instead of index/match.

Comment: Yes you're right that is useless. I commented "On Error Resume Next" out and the problem still persists.

Comment: The combination of removing `On Error Resume Next` and setting `State` below the data pull worked. Its running like it should now. Thanks so much for the help! Also, I'm using index match since I'm flipping between workbooks - not sure its the best but was what I'm used to.